# Does the Mitsubishi Pajero io 2006 have an AUX input?

Tags: audio, mitsubishi, pajero

The radio on this Mitsubishi Pajero io (2006) has aux listed as an input source option but I don't see an aux plug anywhere.

Comment: Inside the center console compartment?

Comment: By “option” do you mean an installed port on the radio or an “option” that needed to be specified and paid for when completing the initial purchase?

Comment: @SolarMike I mean when you press the source button one of the options that eventually come up is aux but I don't see the port anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out there isn't an aux input anywhere in the car. I just bought an FM transmitter so I can play songs in the car through aux.